# How to get data from controls in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have repeater with item template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="queryParametersRepeater" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="queryParametersObjectDataSource">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="itemTemplate">
      <td class="labelTd" style="width: 300px;">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ParameterType") %>' />
        Define <%# Eval("ParameterName") %> (type <%# Eval("ParameterType") %>)
      </td>                        
      <td class="valueTd">                            
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="300px" Text='<%# Eval("ParameterName") %>' />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Width="300px" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>                
</asp:Repeater>
```

In jQuery I change display property of textBox and chekBox. How can I get data from those controls?

I can't use `FindControls()` function, because I don't know id of my controls.

Comment: As @Chris has suggested, you must have ID to your control for referring it at server side code. Then you have to use `FindControl` with that ID on correct naming container. In case of Repeater, each repeater item will act as naming container.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use ID's and findcontrol to get the values.  Here is a working example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //bind the data source
            RepeaterExample.DataSource = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>{
                new KeyValuePair<int,  string>(1, "Test1"), 
                new KeyValuePair<int,  string>(2, "Test2"), 
                new KeyValuePair<int,  string>(3, "Test3")
            };
            RepeaterExample.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //read the values and output them
            litResults.Text = "";
            foreach (RepeaterItem i in RepeaterExample.Items)
            {

                TextBox txtExample = (TextBox)i.FindControl("txtExample");
                if (txtExample != null)
                {
                    litResults.Text += txtExample.Text + "<br />";
                }
            }
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterExample" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        test</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExample" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater><br />
                <asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="cmdSubmit_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="litResults" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is work...a lot of thanks. Before your answer i use FindCotrol() too, but i add id dynamicly with jquery, and it doesn't work

Comment: But i can't detect what control is visible, checkbox or textbox

Comment: how are you setting the visibility.  If you are setting with the .Visible property server side so that the control is not rendered then you should be able to check the property value.

Comment: @Alex, if you set the ids of your controls using jQuery, only the clients will know the ids; the server won't. I don't think `FindControl` knows what the user's DOM tree looks like.

Answer (score -2):

Can you add a class to your controls?
If so you could try with `$(".givenClass").`